# JS - How to detect when browser refuses local files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The source of a local image files, e.g. when pasted from Office Word into an editable div is not allowed by a browser. How to detect that this error message has been throuwn?

ERROR

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image003.jpg
```

HTML

```
<img width="403" height="403" src="file:///C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\msohtmlclip1\01\clip_image003.jpg" v:shapes="Grafik_x0020_2">
```